# How do I set a default value on a bit field using Entity Framework Core code-first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>()
        .Property(s => s.FlagTrainedOnly)
        .HasDefaultValue(false);
}
```

And the error I get:

> Error CS1061
>   'PropertyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasDefaultValue' and no extension method 'HasDefaultValue' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Any suggestion from Ctrl+dot? Like `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`? Also make sure you have referenced `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly.

Comment: That fixed it. I wasn't referencing Relational (as apparently my EF Core was not updated).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've got

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

at the top and then try putting it on one line like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().Property(p => p.FlagTrainedOnly).HasDefaultValue(false);
}
```

Then put it on multiple lines. I think sometimes it needs to be reminded that the dot extensions exist.

Comment: Doesn't work. I also get an error that `PropertyBuilder<int>` doesn't have a definition for `HasDefaultValue` using EF Core 2.1.4. Strange.